# Can one define the $\omega$th term of a geometric sequence?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Consider the infinite geometric sequence, defined as

$$a_n=a_0|r|^{|n|} : r \in \mathbb{Z}^+$$

As the number of terms in the sequence is unbounded, it seems reasonable that one can define a term in the sequence that is indexed by a transfinite ordinal. Is there any set theoretical objection to defining terms such as $a_{\omega_0}, a_{\omega_1}, a_{\omega_2}, \dots$, therefore implying values such as $a_{\omega_0}=a_0|r|^{\aleph_0}$? This question is particularly motivated by a binary tree and the consideration of whether or not an $\omega_0$th row exists within the tree.

I had a bit of a debate with the editor of a journal (an expert in set theory) recently about this. He was reluctant to permit such a definition but was evasive in stating his reasoning.

Comment: You can define whatever you want, anytime, anywhere. There are never restrictions. The restrictions come from what properties you want it to satisfy, but you haven't mentioned any.

Comment: Not sure that it makes sense to exponentiate a real number by an infinite cardinal, but it can make sense to exponentiate ordinal and cardinal numbers by ordinals and cardinals respectively.

Comment: The value of $r$ is implied as a cardinal number. I've edited the definition for clarity.

Comment: Do you intend for the series to end *somewhere* (e.g. for all ordinals below $\omega_{42}$), or to span all ordinals or cardinals? In the latter case, you need to be more careful as you no longer have an ordinary function, but a class function.

Comment: @conditionalMethod: The properties that I wish to satisfy are derived from the geometry of the binary tree I have alluded to.

Comment: @conditionalMethod: There are restrictions as soon as you get into proper class territory. Like the fact that in ZFC you cannot define the set of all sets. Possibly more relevant in this case, you also cannot define the set of all ordinals.

Comment: @MasterDrifter: In principle ordinal-sized binary trees are possible (see the surreal numbers for an example). It's just that if your tree spans *all* ordinals (or all cardinals, for that matter), you'll have to be careful, as some things you take for granted may no longer hold, since you're now dealing with proper classes.

Comment: Please do not add superfluous tags ("large cardinal" is a technical term). The question belongs to elementary set theory, please do not add the other tag.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: This question does indeed involve large cardinals, as they are defined in the function of interest.

Comment: @MasterDrifter They are not defined in the function of interest. [Large cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal) are *vastly* bigger than anything being described in the OP. *(In particular: $\aleph_0$ is not a large cardinal, $2^{\aleph_0}$ is not a large cardinal, the least $\kappa$ satisfying [$\beth_\kappa$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number)$=\kappa$ is not a large cardinal, ...)*

Comment: @MasterDrifter: No, it does not. Andrés is correct here.

Comment: My mistake, apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short version: sort of but not very satisfyingly.

---

For $r,a,n$ possibly infinite cardinals, cardinal multiplication and cardinal exponentiation do indeed give meaning to the expression $r\cdot a^n$. However, fixing $r$ and $a$, as a function of $n$ this isn't very interesting since cardinal arithmetic is so "coarse." For example, as long as $a,r\le 2^{\aleph_0}$ (and $r>1$) we'll always have $a\cdot r^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ since $$2^{\aleph_0}\cdot (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}\cdot 2^{\aleph_0\cdot \aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}.$$ So things get pretty boring.

Ordinal arithmetic is somewhat more interesting than cardinal arithmetic, but it still trivializes a lot in this case. In particular, for any finite $n$ we have $$n^\omega=\sup_{k\in\omega}n^k=\omega$$ in the sense of ordinal exponentiation.

This is an instance of a more general situation: "ordinary" mathematical operations often only extend into the transfinite at the cost of losing lots of the original nature. Cardinal exponentiation is a good positive example of this: [it *is* incredibly interesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_cardinals_hypothesis), but completely fails to look like ordinary exponentiation - and indeed the key ingredient which makes cardinal exponentiation interesting (namely *cofinality*) doesn't even make sense at the finite level.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of the differences in ordinal and cardinal arithmetic, and the final result of $2^{\aleph_0}$ is actually my only interest here.

Comment: @MasterDrifter In that case, the $\omega$th term of any "cardinalized" geometric series with countable ratio $>1$ and countable coefficient $>0$ is always $2^{\aleph_0}$ (and relatedly, for any cardinal $\kappa$ between $2$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ inclusive we have $\kappa^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$).

Comment: I agree. This was the result that was in dispute with the editor. It appears that his argument was baseless.

Comment: @MasterDrifter Without seeing the exchange, I can't express an opinion on that. However, it's quite possible (likely, even) that the editor was saying that it is "morally" impossible - in the sense that any generalization to ordinal-length sequences is going to break with the classical situation to such an extreme degree that it doesn't really count as a "generalization." (In my opinion that'd be fair.)

Comment: Relatedly, your mention of whether the infinite binary tree has an $\omega_0$th row (it doesn't) suggests that you may have been trying to argue for a claim about infinite sets by lifting properties of classical geometric series to "cardinalized" geometric series, and that's certainly not possible. (There's also the separate issue of what to do if $r$ is a real number as opposed to a cardinal - you restricted attention to cardinals in the comments, but did not do so in the question itself.)

Comment: @MasterDrifter: This is about context. When people think about a geometric sequence, people tend to think about $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, or something similar to that. In this context, it is indeed impossible to define $r^{\aleph_0}$ (or $r^\omega$) when $r$ is a real number, since real numbers are *not* cardinal (or ordinal) numbers. Unless you clarify this in advance, I would be also tell you that this is impossible, because that's what I'd think you are trying to do.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Cardinal exponentiation between two cardinals $A=|a|$ and $B=|b|$ of the form $A^B$ evaluates the number of functions  that  map  any  set  of $A$ elements  to  any  set  of $B$ elements.  Consider an $a$ and $b$ such that $a=\{L,R\}$ and $b=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ where $L$ and $R$ denote left and right.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The cardinality of $A^B$ can be interpreted as the  number  of  possible  paths  through  a  bifurcating tree, after $n$ bifurcations.  For example, if n=3, the possible paths from the root of the tree are $LLL, RRR, LLR,LRL, RLL, RRL, RLR, LRR$, of which there are $2^3=8$, i.e., the number of nodes in row 3 of the tree.

Comment: @NoahSchweber This appears to permit the "cardinalized" geometric series, as you put it, no?

Comment: @MasterDrifter So what? None of this is going to get around the fact that you can't really use facts about finite exponentiation or geometric series to deduce very much about the infinite case. (In particular you can't use the continuity of classical exponentiation to prove that the continuum is countable, since you can't conclude that cardinal exponentiation should be continuous; this is a fairly common issue FWIW.) Just because something makes sense doesn't mean it's going to be useful for a given problem.

Comment: @AsafKaragila The issue of whether $r$ is real is a matter of a typo in the original question—not of the actual matter at hand. The question has been fixed. Thank you.

Comment: @MasterDrifter: You haven't *truly* clarified the context. Since you write $r\in\Bbb Z^+$, you are not telling me if you're thinking about $r$ as a real number, or as an ordinal number, or as a cardinal number. The three notions certainly coincide on $\Bbb Z^+$, but this is exactly where ambiguity makes people reluctant to give a concrete answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber If you would like to amend your answer to the question regarding why exactly a binary tree does not have an $\omega_0$ row, please do so. That is my main interest here.

Comment: @MasterDrifter It doesn't have one because that's not how it's defined: it's defined as the set of all finite binary sequences. I'm not sure what more there is to say. (If you're using a different definition you should specify that.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber What doesn't sit right with me is that if $\omega_0$ is an ordinal that supposedly occurs in the sequence of ordinals, what is preventing the existence of a row in the binary tree that is indexed by $\omega_0$? It seems to me that if one refuses to accept such a row, then the definition of $\omega_0$ as an ordinal, i.e., an index, is a contradiction.

Comment: @MasterDrifter An *analogue* of the usual binary tree (usually denoted "$2^{<\omega}$") of height $\omega+1$ (that is, with an $\omega$th row) can indeed be defined (and it's usually denoted "$2^{\le\omega}$," unsurprisingly). But it's not the same thing as the usual binary tree. So there's no tension; you're conflating two different objects. (In particular, just because we *can* continue past the finite doesn't mean we *have* to.)